# Mapreduce output showing all records in same line

Tags: elastic-map-reduce

I have implemented a mapreduce operation for log file using amazon and hadoop with custom jar.

My output shows the correct keys and values, but all the records are being displayed in a single line. For example, given the following pairs:

```
<1387, 2>
<1388, 1>
```

This is what's printing:

```
1387     21388     1
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
1387     2
1388     1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you print out the records? As it stands, we have no clue what you're doing! (My guess is that you're missing adding a newline character)

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
   
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(LogAnalyzer.class);
      conf.setJobName("Loganalyzer");

      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      conf.setMapperClass(LogAnalyzer.Map.class);
      conf.setCombinerClass(LogAnalyzer.Reduce.class);
      conf.setReducerClass(LogAnalyzer.Reduce.class); conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
      conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", "--");

Comment: FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

      JobClient.runJob(conf);
      
   }

Comment: Reduce function : public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
          sum += values.next().get();
        }
       
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
    }

Comment: Map function:      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

       String line = ((Text) value).toString();
       Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
       if (matcher.matches()) {
         String timestamp = matcher.group(4);
         minute.set(getMinuteBucket(timestamp));
         output.collect(minute, ONE);
         //context.write(minute, one);
       }

     }

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your code for you :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(LogAnalyzer.class);
    conf.setJobName("Loganalyzer");
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(LogAnalyzer.Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(LogAnalyzer.Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(LogAnalyzer.Reduce.class);
    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", "--");
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf); 
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> { 
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
        int sum = 0; 
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get(); 
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum)); 
    } 
}


public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = ((Text) value).toString(); 
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line); 
    if (matcher.matches()) { 
        String timestamp = matcher.group(4); 
        minute.set(getMinuteBucket(timestamp)); 
        output.collect(minute, ONE); //context.write(minute, one); 
    }
}
```

This isn't hadoop-streaming, it's just a normal java job. You should amend the tag on the question.

This looks okay to me, although you don't have the mapper inside a class, which I assume is a copy/paste omission.

With regards to the line endings. I don't suppose you are looking at the output on Windows? It could be a problem with unix/windows line endings. If you open up the file in sublime or another advanced text editor you can switch between unix and windows. See if that works.